# Are $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic as groups?

Tags: group-theory

To be clear, by $\mathbb Z$ I mean the group $(\mathbb Z, +)$.

My intuitive answer would be no, but I haven't been able to find a proof for it. The basic invariants I know of (e.g. order of elements) are not useful here and my knowledge of infinite abelian groups is very limited.

In general, is it true that $\mathbb Z^n \cong \mathbb Z^m \iff n=m$?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification.

Comment: Isn't it possible to prove that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be generated by two elements? (where "generated" means that every element in the group can be written as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of the two fixed ones) Since $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ can indeed be generated by two elements, the result would follow. This might not be the most elegant way of showing it, but maybe a more insightful way.

Comment: @Joachim: And the most clumsiest way. (Write down the direct proof and you will see why)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, yes i suspected that. However for a proof, don't being clumsy and giving insight often overlap?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Elementary solution.** If $\mathbb{Z}^n \cong \mathbb{Z}^m$, then $\mathbb{Z}^n / 2 \mathbb{Z}^n \cong \mathbb{Z}^m / 2 \mathbb{Z}^m$, i.e. $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^m$. Counting gives $2^n=2^m$, i.e. $n=m$.

The same proof shows: If $R$ is a commutative ring which has a finite nontrivial quotient ring, then $R^n \cong R^m$ as $R$-modules implies $n=m$. It is known that this even holds for arbitrary commutative rings, and various proofs are available.

Answer (score 5):

Tensor them against $\Bbb Q$ as $\Bbb Z$-modules and you can consider a simple vector space invariant.